# libvirt qemu/kvm migration problem

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I am using kvm and libvirt on my Dell server. Now i am trying to migrate one virtual machine from a physical server to another. However, I failed everytime.

In virsh on physicalServer1, I typed:

```
virsh # migrate virtualmachine1 qemu+ssh://username@physicalServer2/system
error: operation failed: migration to 'tcp:physicalServer2:49163' failed: migration failed
```

Then I searched [FAQ part on libvirt.org](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/FAQ). It says:

```
error: operation failed: migration to '...' failed: migration failed

This is an error often encountered when trying to migrate with QEMU/KVM. This typically happens with plain migration, when the source VM cannot connect to the destination host. You will want to make sure your hosts are properly configured for migration (see the migration section of this FAQ)
```

I managed to `ssh physicalServer2` from a shell on virtualmachine1 so the above red part did not explain my failure.

I also open ports on physicalServer2, `iptables -L` shows following information:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW tcp dpts:49152:49215


Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
ACCEPT all -- anywhere 192.168.122.0/24 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT all -- 192.168.122.0/24 anywhere
ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere
REJECT all -- anywhere anywhere reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT all -- anywhere anywhere reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT all -- anywhere 192.168.122.0/24 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT all -- 192.168.122.0/24 anywhere
ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere
REJECT all -- anywhere anywhere reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT all -- anywhere anywhere reject-with icmp-port-unreachable


Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
```

The /var/log/libvirt/qemu/virtualmachine1.log on physicalServer2:

```
2011-05-06 13:37:30.708: starting up
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none /usr/bin/kvm -S -M pc-0.14 -enable-kvm -m 2048 -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 -name openjudge-test -uuid a8c704bc-a4f9-90db-3e57-40e60b00aac1 -nodefconfig -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/virtualmachine1.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=readline -rtc base=utc -boot c -drive file=/media/nfs/virtualmachine1.img,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,format=raw -device ide-drive,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0 -drive if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive-ide0-1-0,readonly=on,format=raw -device ide-drive,bus=ide.1,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-1-0,id=ide0-1-0 -netdev tap,fd=20,id=hostnet0 -device rtl8139,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=00:16:36:8a:22 :a0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -usb -vnc 127.0.0.1:2 -vga cirrus -incoming tcp:0.0.0.0:49163 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4
char device redirected to /dev/pts/0
2011-05-06 13:37:30.915: shutting down
```

The /var/log/libvirt/qemu/virtualmachine1.log on physicalServer1 is empty.

Both physical servers are using Ubuntu 11.04. The libvirt and kvm used are installed by apt-get. The libvirt version is 0.8.8.

Comment: where is the VM's image? does both of the servers have access to this image and sees it on the same path? does physicalServer2 have full rw access to the image?

Comment: also, make sure that the libvirt user can ssh to the physicalServer2 (have the server's rsa key in its known_hosts, and better to have ssh keys setup for libvirt users)

Comment: I'd also try to get rid of firewalls completely, as a test

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have TCP 49152-49261 open between the hosts and the hostnames for each in either DNS or each other's /etc/hosts files.  For some reason KVM migration works off of hostname rather than IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both host servers are on the same physical switch (or VLAN).